# File data\SPY.csv does not exist

Tags: python, csv

Just started learning python and trying to read a CSV file with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "C:\\Anaconda\\SPY.csv"))
```

But I get the error:

```
File data\SPY.csv does not exist
```

Tried with both one and two / and \ and ' instead of "

this is the connection string: `C:\Anaconda\SPY.csv`

(This is a file from yahoo finance. I first tried to call to yahoo but was unable so instead I just downloaded the file and saved it as a CSV)

Comment: If you are not sure of what is being passed, try printing it first to see what it is doing, e.g. `print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "C:\\Anaconda\\SPY.csv") `. This would help you understand what the problem is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because you are trying to join your current directory which is named "data" but your file is actually in "Anaconda".

Try a simple

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Anaconda\\SPY.csv")
```

If you really want to use `os.path.join`, this should do:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = os.path.join("C:","Anaconda","SPY.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(path)
```

Also, if your SPY.csv file is in the same directory as your Python file, you should replace the path with a simple `SPY.csv`

Comment: If you use `os.path.join` with two absolute paths, the second will overwrite the first. Which leaves me confused where 'data' is coming from in the OP

Comment: Thank you, yes it solved the problem to move the file from /data.

My first problem was to import the dataset from yahoo. Any ideas how to do that?